# How to allow users to download app that google chrome blocks it as malware

Tags: website, malware, chrome

I have an Android App which allows users to spy or monitor their dependents device remotely. User has to download the app, register by providing email id and password and go to our website, login with same username and password and then pull information from device by clicking on buttons. No information is transferred from device automatically to server. So it's perfectly safe.

But now google is blocking the download of this apk by throwing a message "The site ahead contains malware", and this has reduced the number of downloads of the app.

My question to expert and experienced people is: How can i store in website or any other website so that google will NOT block the download. Is there any third party website which stores and allows for download by having a dynamic URL or in any way that it knows how to escape these blockings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question under the *"unauthorized use or misuse of IT systems"* reason listed in the [Help Center](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Regardless of the specifics of why you are seeking mechanics to dodge Chrome's malware list, we have to consider the wider audience and who will really be putting these answers to use.

Comment: @AndrewB I must tell that chrome detect some legit tool as malware too, not the first time I see that error.

Comment: "So it's perfectly safe." It doesn't sound all that safe.

Comment: @AndrewB it was just to brainstorm on the possibility of having a solution and how others are doing it (as i have seen many of my competitors do it but just don't know how)

Comment: @ceejayoz I meant It's just safe from our side that the data is not misused (or rather used in any way) as that's the fear chrome is putting to the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chrome detect some remote connection tool as malware. [Ammyy admin](http://ammyy.com) is one of them too.

nb, Google offer some help for dev in case of false warning. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249

Re-compile your app could help, a filehash/signature got triggered on your file (or encode your runtime, so it decompress in memory at runtime), or ask your user to uncheck to Check for malware, (printscreen took from [there](http://www.shoutmeloud.com/disable-chrome-warning-the-website-ahead-contains-malware.html)) or ask them to use another browser.

[image]

Comment: Users are told to ignore the warning with a javascript alert message and most of them are ignoring it. Will try to change the signature and see.

Comment: Why the downvote? even google told how to bypass their security check for false warning. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249